# Apache Spark JDBC DataFrame count issue

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, mssql-jdbc

I am using Spark JDBC to read data from MS SQL database, but I am getting some weird results.

For example, below is my code  to read records from my MS SQL database.
Please note the tables from which I am reading data is continuously getting inserted with records.

```
 //Extract Data from JDBC source
    val jdbcTable = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(
      Map(
        "url" -> jdcbUrl,
        "driver" -> "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver",
        "dbtable" ->
          s"(SELECT COLUMNS WITH INNER JOINS WHERE tbl.ID > ${lastExtractUnixTime}) as t"))
       .load

     println(s"STEP 1] JDBC RECORDS COUNTS ---> ${jdbcTable.count()}")

    val updateJdbcDF = jdbcTable
      .withColumn("ID-COL1", trim($"COl1"))
      .withColumn("ID-COL1", trim($"COl2"))

   println(s"STEP 2] UPDATE JDBC RECORDS COUNTS ---> ${updateJdbcDF.count()}")
```

I get 2 different count values each time I run my program, for example I always get `${updateJdbcDF.count()}` count >  `${jdbcTable.count()}`.

Can somebody explain me why is this happening? This is creating a lot of issues in my use case.  How to restrict count of `jdbcTable` DataFrame after it is created. I tried `jdbcTable.cache()` but no luck.

The records just gets  bigger and bigger when I use any operation on other dataframe derived from `jdbcTable` DataFrame. Does `jdbcTable` dataframe call every time I use any dataframe derived from `jdbcTable` dataframe.

Comment: Is the difference constant? Or are you getting different counts for both statements every time?

Comment: @philantrovert No difference is not constant, I am getting different count each time..

Comment: Well if "the tables from which I am reading data is continuously getting inserted with records" and your request does not define a fixed range predicate, then the number of rows in the table is different each time sparks accesses it. So what you are seeing (changing counts) is only to be expected, isn't it ?

Comment: @GPI, OK, that means If my predicate is absent, then whenever I use any dataframe derived from the jdbcTable dataframe then a spark will read again from the DB and will always give me higher count right?? Actually, this is what I am observing from my code as well jdbcTable is the first DF and when I add some columns and make another DF such as updateJdbcDF ; count get increased as spark has re-read the table.

Comment: @nilesh1212 this is a "grey" area. Spark will "do its best" not to recompute any RDD / dataframe that it can avoid (and even allows you to cache them). *But* it will go back to the datastores (be them Databases through JDBC, Parquet files on HDFS, ...) if it has to recompute part of its execution graph that has not been cached. Which kind of clashes with some basic assumptions one can make : RDDs (and by extension dataframes) are supposed to be immutable, but if they're backed by dynamic data, they can not be, and one needs to code accordingly to the nature of their source.

Comment: @GPI, Thank you for the reply, I was able to fix this issue by applying jdbcTable.cache(), Now any DF derived from jdbcTable dataframe does not give me a higher count than jdbcTable.count(). All calculations are OK now.

Comment: OK, just be careful that if you ever come to a situation where your dataframe can not be cached (not enough RAM ?) Spark may fallback to the SQL server and re-query. To be extra sure, using an upperBound to the queried elements (date or id) might do the trick. It's your call in the end :-).

Comment: @GPI Sure , I will handle mentioned scenario as well, will update my answer accordingly  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this issue by applying `jdbcTable.cache()`, Now any DF derived from jdbcTable dataframe does not give me a higher count than `jdbcTable.count()`. All calculations are OK now. Thanks for the explanation @GPI

```
//Extract Data from JDBC source
    val jdbcTable = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(
      Map(
        "url" -> jdcbUrl,
        "driver" -> "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver",
        "dbtable" ->
          s"(SELECT COLUMNS WITH INNER JOINS WHERE tbl.ID > ${lastExtractUnixTime}) as t"))
       .load

    jdbcTable.cache()

     println(s"STEP 1] JDBC RECORDS COUNTS ---> ${jdbcTable.count()}")


    val updateJdbcDF = jdbcTable
      .withColumn("ID-COL1", trim($"COl1"))
      .withColumn("ID-COL1", trim($"COl2"))

   println(s"STEP 2] UPDATE JDBC RECORDS COUNTS ---> ${updateJdbcDF.count()}")
   /**
     * MORE DATA PROCESSING HERE
   /**

  jdbcTable.unpersist()
```